# Meteor Filter Data in List by Clicking on Sidebar Categories

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a list of categories that appear in a sidebar (for instance: food, toys, clothes, etc.).

In the content I have a list of items each of which belong to a category.  I want a user to be able to sort that list by clicking on the appropriate category in the sidebar.

For instance, if they click solely on Food then only items from the food category will appear.  If they ALSO click on Toys then items from BOTH the food and toys category will appear.

How can I set this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Template.filters.onCreated(function () {
  this.filters = new ReactiveVar({});
});

Template.filters.helpers({
  categories: function () {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    return Categories.find(instance.filters.get());
  }
});

Template.filters.events({
  // whenever a select is changed
  'change select.category-filter': function (e, template) {
    const categories = $(e.target).find('option:checked').reduce(function (query, node) {
      query[node.data.name] = this.value;
      return query;
    }, {});
    template.filters.set(categories); 
  }
});
```

The reactive var will change, updating the helper, and in turn updating the query.